# How do I disable (or replace the effect of) "overscrolling" in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, touchpad, scrolling, microsoft-surface, user-experience

I'm an OSX user and don't like that the scrolling feature moves the entire window on Windows 10.  This creates a jarring effect on the entire screen, when I'm dealing with only a particular document.

Outlook, with a preview pane, in full screen is an excellent example.

IMHO, When I scroll down (or up) excessively, I don't expect the entire app to respond with a shake.  Rather, the document (email for example) should respond, or nothing at all.

How do I disable the "window shake" when I scroll up / down past the beginning or ending?

Comment: It is just the active window that shakes? I am using Windows 10 on a touch-screen laptop, but this sounds like a Surface-only "feature" so I cannot reproduce. Have you tried disabling some of the Visual Effects in System Properties -> Advanced -> Performance? Turning off the animation options might do the trick.

Comment: Other names of this are: elastic scroll, scroll above the edge, scroll top bounce. No luck finding a solution, though. Some people want to fix this specifically for Excel, had no luck finding a fix either.

Answer (score 0):

Open `regedit.exe` using `Win + R` or type in `Registry Editor` and locate `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Wisp\Touch`. Then right-click the key for `Bouncing` and click `Modify...`. Then change the value from `1` (enabled) to `0` (disabled) and press `OK`. After that, restart and the changes should be applied.

---

Reference: http://errorfixer.co/disable-overscroll-animation-windows-10/